# how to change the default port 8080 when I am using EnableAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, thymeleaf

I have developed a project using this link:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/
I used maven to develop above project.
After creating the jar file using mvn package, when I run the jar file using below command:

> > java - jar target/gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar

It runs on port 8080, but I want it to be run on some different port other than 8080.

I tried a lot to search its answer but no use.

Please help me out in this as its blocking me for long time now.

Thanks and best reagrds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the following file: `src/main/resources/aplication.properties`and add this content:

```
server.port: 9000
management.port: 9001
management.address: 127.0.0.1
```

[Source](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/), jump to section "Switch to a different server port"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was struggling for it for last 2 days.

Comment: Glad it was useful, I just worked through this yesterday, so the timing was great.